# PHP variables in a complex way

Tags: php, arrays, count, echo

```
<?php
$td = date("d");

for ($i = 1; $i <= $td; $i++)
{
  $num18 = count($this->numbermonth18);
  echo "['1'," . $num18 . "],";
}
```

The above code will display the output like, **['1',12],['1',12],['1',12],['1',12],['1',12],['1',12],['1',12],['1',12],['1',12],['1',12],['1',12],['1',12],['1',12],['1',12],['1',12],['1',12],['1',12],['1',12],['1',12],['1',12],['1',12],['1',12],['1',12],['1',12],['1',12],['1',12],['1',12],['1',12],['1',12],['1',12],**.

I need to replace the 18 with `$i` value in the above code. How can I use `$i` instead of 18 in the for loop to display all the values of `$this->numbermonth1`, `$this->numbermonth2`, `$this->numbermonth3` etc. and print the array?

Comment: You are most likely looking for something called *Variable Variables* in PHP: http://php.net/language.variables.variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do with:

```
for($i=1;$i<=$td;$i++)
{
  $num=count($this->{'numbermonth'.$i});
  echo "['1',".$num."],";
}
```